# Align EditText to fill rest of Constraint Layout, but position it relative to a sibling

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext, android-constraintlayout

I have a ConstraintLayout with some margin on each of its sides. Within it, I have 2 EditText views, the first is a single line (let's call this ET1) whereas the second is multi-line (let's call this ET2).

I want to make the position of ET2 relative to ET1, specifically so that ET2 is right below ET1. However, I also want ET2 to fill the rest of the ConstraintLayout.

In short, it would look something like (where "---" denote the boundaries of the ConstraintLayout):

```
---
ET1
ET2
ET2
ET2
---
```

Right now for ET2, I have:

```
layout_height="match_parent"
layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="ET1"
```

This does make ET2 fill the entire ConstraintLayout, but as a result, ET1 and ET2 are on top of one another (i.e. layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="ET1" is not respected). Is there something I can do to satisfy both the positioning and sizing requirements? Thanks!

Here's an example of what I want it to look like:
[image: example]

The key here is that ET2 is under ET1 because it is relative to ET1, not because I set a margin on ET2 relative to the ConstraintLayout.

EDIT: I figured it out! Thanks for the answer - I ended up using just the ConstraintLayout attributes to position the EditText view and then instead of using match_parent, I provided "0dp" as the layout_height :)

Comment: Please check updated image in question, it is not loading.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="editText1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="EdiText2 \nMultiple Line"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/et1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/et1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et1" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! I pasted the code into my work and it seems like it is creating ET1, but when you actually run the application, ET2 doesn't appear at all.

Comment: EditText E2 appears, but due to match parent constraint it look like not appears, but when you write something on it, you will definitely see the edittext

Answer (score 0):

You can use `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".2"` on the top text view so it will only take 20% of the  screen height and `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".8"` so it will take 80% of the screen height.

By doing this you will get your wanted look:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".2"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:text="I am edit text"
    android:gravity="top"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
    android:text="I am fat edit text"
    android:gravity="top"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".8"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />


 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**And it will look like this:**

[image]